# Manipulate data output from get(this.props 'data')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using **ReactJS** and **GatsbyJS** with data pulled from **Contentful** using **GraphQL**.

Getting the data is okay but on this occasion, using the **`react-photo-gallery`** ([Github](https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery)) the data pulled does not match requirements.

**Here is an example of the GraphQL Query**

```
query galleryQuery($slug: String!) {
   contentfulImageGallery(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      summerGallery {
         sizes(maxWidth: 1500) {
            ...GatsbyContentfulSizes_withWebp_noBase64
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**And by defining the data**

```
const summerGallery = get(this.props, 'data.contentfulImageGallery')
```

**I get a JSON response of**

```
{
 "data": {
    "contentfulImageGallery": {
      "summerGallery": [
        {
          "sizes": {
            "aspectRatio": 1.7779433681073025,
            "sizes": "(max-width: 1500px) 100vw, 1500px",
            "src": "http://example.com/example/img1.jpg?w=1500&q=50"
          }
        },
        {
          "sizes": {
            "aspectRatio": 1.7779433681073025,
            "sizes": "(max-width: 1500px) 100vw, 1500px",
            "src": "http://example.com/example/img2.jpg?w=1500&q=50"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I manipulate this data so that I can use the images within

```
<Gallery photos={summerGallery}/>
```

as

```
const summerGallery = [
  {
    src: 'http://example.com/example/img1.jpg'
    width: "NEED WIDTH"
    height: "NEED HEIGHT"
  },
  {
    src: 'http://example.com/example/img2.jpg'
    width: "NEED WIDTH"
    height: "NEED HEIGHT"
  }
]
```

I though that I could get the src by `{summerGallery.sizes.src}` but it returns `undefined` in the console and a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined` on page. The width and height, zero idea.

Comment: Isnt it summerGallery[0].sizes.src or summerGallery[1].sizes.src and so on? You are trying to get an object within an array. you should get an array object and then objects within it

Comment: That is correct. It is something that I need to spend some more time understanding - Thank you.

Comment: Does it really return `undefined`? `summerGallery.sizes.src` should actually throw a `TypeError` because summerGallery is an array that has no property `sizes`. Therefore `sizes` will be already `undefined`. And accessing `src` on `undefined` should throw a `TypeError`. Something like: "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined".

Comment: Yes, when `const summerGallery = get(this.props, 'data.contentfulImageGallery.summerGallery.src')`. In `console.log(summerGallery)` returns `undefined`. I believe that when creating the gallery it was throwing a `TypeError` as you mentioned.

Comment: Okay I see. But that is different to what you wrote: "I though that I could get the src by {summerGallery.sizes.src} but it returns undefined." while in reality that must throw an error. It created a little bit of confusion for me.

Comment: Understood, I updated for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summerGallery.sizes.src` is undefined because `summerGallery` is an Array with no `sizes` property.

You can `map` the `summerGallery` array to the required format:

```
const mappedDataArray = summerGallery.map(g => {
  return {
    src: g.sizes.src,
    width: '100vw',
    height: '1500px',
  }
})
```